# How to create a function to get sum of Colors from given array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to create a function to get sum of Colors given in this array.

This is my array-

```
$sales = array(
    'FIRST'=> array('RED'=> array(9,3),'GREEN'=> array(4,5,8,2)),     
    'SECOND'=> array('RED'=> array(3,5,5,2),'YELLOW'=> array(4,2,5)),     
    'THIRD'=> array('BLUE'=> array(1,2,4),'RED'=> array(9,4,6)),    
    'FOUR'=> array('BLUE'=> array(2,3,3,5),'BLACK'=> array(4,5,8,9))
);
```

Expected output:

```
('RED'=>21,'GREEN=>'..etc)
```

Comment: How your RED value comes out as __21__???

Comment: Write a function that loops out the first array that is FIRST, SECOND....write another looping that strips The colors as the key then use array_sum on the values

Comment: @rijin: explain your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not responding with any message, from your Expected output here is a solution. Make two loops for getting the color array value with the key, now each color has another array and from that you need to pick the first element and add into the color index of another array.

```
$output = array();
foreach($sales as $val){
    foreach($val as $key => $value){
        if(isset($output[$key]))
            $output[$key] += $value[0];
        else
            $output[$key] = $value[0];
    }
}

print_r($output); // Array ( [RED] => 21 [GREEN] => 4 [YELLOW] => 4 [BLUE] => 3 [BLACK] => 4 )
```

Check this, I think this is helpful to you.